# Azure B2C Net Core Development Workflow

Tags: azure, session, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I've cloned the following repository [active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0) and are using it as a starting point for a new application. Everything works as expected until I recompile my code after a code change. It seems that the acquireTokenSilent function returns a session expired message whenever I recompile my app during the normal development process. This is obviously problematic as it forces me to re-authenticate to my azure tenant after every code change. Perhaps this has more to do with the .net core caching strategy that is configured than azure b2c. Here is the authentication middleware in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
        .AddCookie();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });


    }
```

As well as the  class that is handling the token cache:

```
   public class MSALSessionCache
    {
        private static ReaderWriterLockSlim SessionLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);
        string UserId = string.Empty;
        string CacheId = string.Empty;
        HttpContext httpContext = null;

        TokenCache cache = new TokenCache();



   public MSALSessionCache(string userId, HttpContext httpcontext)
    {
        // not object, we want the SUB
        UserId = userId;
        CacheId = UserId + "_TokenCache";
        httpContext = httpcontext;
        Load();
    }

    public TokenCache GetMsalCacheInstance()
    {
        cache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
        cache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        Load();
        return cache;
    }

    public void SaveUserStateValue(string state)
    {
        SessionLock.EnterWriteLock();
        httpContext.Session.SetString(CacheId + "_state", state);
        SessionLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
    public string ReadUserStateValue()
    {
        string state = string.Empty;
        SessionLock.EnterReadLock();
        state = (string)httpContext.Session.GetString(CacheId + "_state");
        SessionLock.ExitReadLock();
        return state;
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        SessionLock.EnterReadLock();
        cache.Deserialize(httpContext.Session.Get(CacheId));
        SessionLock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    public void Persist()
    {
        SessionLock.EnterWriteLock();

        // Optimistically set HasStateChanged to false. We need to do it early to avoid losing changes made by a concurrent thread.
        cache.HasStateChanged = false;

        // Reflect changes in the persistent store
        httpContext.Session.Set(CacheId, cache.Serialize());
        SessionLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    // Triggered right before MSAL needs to access the cache.
    // Reload the cache from the persistent store in case it changed since the last access.
    void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        Load();
    }

    // Triggered right after MSAL accessed the cache.
    void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
        if (cache.HasStateChanged)
        {
            Persist();
        }
    }
}
```

The session expiration is thrown after acquireTokenSilentAsync is called in the following code block. This only happens after recompiling the app:

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Api()
    {
        string responseString = "";
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
            var scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' ');
            string signedInUserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
            ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault(), AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, false);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl);

            // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Handle the response
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    responseString = $"Please sign in again. {response.ReasonPhrase}";
                    break;
                default:
                    responseString = $"Error calling API. StatusCode=${response.StatusCode}";
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            responseString = $"Session has expired. Please sign in again. {ex.Message}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseString = $"Error calling API: {ex.Message}";
        }

        ViewData["Payload"] = $"{responseString}";            
        return View();
    }
```

Is there a way to have this session persisted after recompile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the token cache.

[The sample README](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0) notes `MSALSessionCache` is an example implementation of a token cache. This example implementation persists the cache data in memory. It doesn't persist the cache data across an application restart or share it across a server farm (unless you have sessions that are sticky).

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for options for persisting the cache data to a distributed cache.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the repository I provided also modifies MsalSessionCache by injecting IDistributedCache cache rather than using tokenCache. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding that many of the azure samples related to B2C authentication are incomplete for common use-cases. Luckily I stumbled upon this [repository](https://github.com/dzimchuk/azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-core) which adds a Reauthenticate global filter. I modified the filter to fit my OpenIdAuthenticationScheme as follows:

```
 internal class ReauthenticationRequiredException : Exception
{
}
internal class ReauthenticationRequiredFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly AzureAdB2COptions _options;

    public ReauthenticationRequiredFilter(IOptions<AzureAdB2COptions> options)
    {
        this._options = options.Value;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ExceptionHandled && IsReauthenticationRequired(context.Exception))
        {

            context.Result = new ChallengeResult(
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = context.HttpContext.Request.Path});


            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsReauthenticationRequired(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is ReauthenticationRequiredException)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            return IsReauthenticationRequired(exception.InnerException);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now after recompiling my app, the app simply redirects to the tenant which seems to refresh the token. I wish I could have upvoted the originial author! Thanks for the contribution.